# How can I transfer the download of images to background thread instead of main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiimageview

I'm currently building an app in which I'm downloading images from the internet (a JSON endpoint to be specific) into the custom cells of my tableview. Everything works great, except for the fact that the images I'm pulling from the JSON string load incredibly slowly when I run the app. Does anyone know how I could make things load faster? Here's my code:

**DoctorsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DoctorsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *DoctorsTableView;

    NSArray *Doctors;
    NSMutableData *data;

}
```

**DoctorsViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL HERE"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    Doctors = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [DoctorsTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure that you're connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [Doctors count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"DoctorsCell";

    DoctorsCell *cell = (DoctorsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DoctorsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.firstnameLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];

    NSString *firstLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

    firstLink = [[[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"] objectForKey:@"filename"];

    NSString *secondLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

    secondLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/sites/default/files/field/image/%@",firstLink];
      NSLog(@"second link is %@", secondLink);

    cell.featureImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]]];

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 373;
}
```

Comment: Most likely the images are large and your connection slow. What is the average file size, how many images are you loading, and what connection are you loading them over?

Comment: And loading the images on the main thread is BAD. Please see the LazyTableImages sample app from Apple.

Comment: @Amadan The images are roughly 640x400 pixels, and load as the user continues to scroll down the table view (number of cells is unlimited). Perhaps I should limit the number of cells to 10?

Comment: 640x400 can go from several dozen bytes (monochrome in gif format) to over one megabyte (e.g. uncompressed 32bit bmp), so it does not really inform anything. If the images are large, you can try squeezing them, reducing the size, caching... (And also, totally do as @rmaddy says)

Comment: @Amadan Would SDWebImage work well in this case? https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @rmaddy So I implemented SDWebImage (creating a background thread), and it works like a charm. Images load so smoothly it's ridiculous :) Thanks for your help!